# Rails test adding unwanted parameter to assert_redirected_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have a test in my functional test which asserts the redirect after a remove is correct:

```
assert_redirected_to terrain_tip_url(terrain_id: entities(:deroos))
```

This should result in testing whether the url is: http://test.host/terrains/:terrain_id/tips and in the application that is the exact url that is generated. However, in the test case this results in the url being: http://test.host/terrains/:terrain_id/tips/:id, which results in a failing test case:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/terrains/446801721/tips/495319887> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/terrains/446801721/tips>
```

Why does the terrain_tip_url include an id parameter that I never set? How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `rake routes` should give you some insight here.  I believe what you want is `terrain_tips_url` (index), not `terrain_tip_url` (show).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Great, thanks! I did indeed want the index, just didn't see I had forgotten the "s" in the function name.